# Can I continue from where I ran out of lives?

Tags: super-contra

In Super Contra, is there a way to continue playing instead of starting back at the beginning when you run out of lives?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way built in to the game. You *can* get 10 extra lives at the title screen when you start the game, though.

Press:
**Right**, **Left**, **Down**, **Up**, **A**, **B** at the title screen and then press **START**.

There are also ways to get infinite lives, infinite continues, etc. but this requires the **Pro Action Replay** cheat device.